# How to know the client is connected Eventhub

Tags: node.js, azure-eventhub

I don't know how to judge the client is connected.
If the EVENTHUB_CONNECTION_STRING is totally wrong, an exception throws.
But what if the key is wrong? If won't throw an exception.
How could I judge the client is connected successfully.

My code is below.

```
var EventHubClient = require('azure-event-hubs').EventHubClient; 

const connectionString = "EVENTHUB_CONNECTION_STRING";
const entityPath = "EVENTHUB_NAME";
const connStr = process.env[connectionString] || "";
const path = process.env[entityPath] || "";

var client = EventHubClient.createFromConnectionString(connStr, path);

 const eventData = {
            body: {
                test1: aaa,
                test2: bbb
            }
        };
await client.send(eventData);
```

Answer (score 0):

`createFromConnectionString(connStr, path)` returns a promise, you should either await it or register a callback for when it resolves with connection or with an error. Also for sending data you need a partition id as well, which can be retrieved with `eventHubClient.getPartitionIds()`

```
var EventHubClient = require('azure-event-hubs').EventHubClient; 

const connectionString = "EVENTHUB_CONNECTION_STRING"; 
const entityPath = "EVENTHUB_NAME"; 
const connStr = process.env[connectionString] || ""; 
const path = process.env[entityPath] || "";

  var client;
  EventHubClient.createFromConnectionString(connStr, path).then((connection) => {
    client = connection;
    ( async function () {
      const pids = client.getPartitionIds();
      const eventData = {
        body: {
          test1: aaa,
          test2: bbb
        }
      };
      pids.forEach((id) => {
        client.send(eventData, id).then((success) => {
          console.log(success);
        }, (error) => {
          console.log(error);

        });

      });
    }())
  }, (connectionError) => {
    console.log(connectionError);
  });
```

Comment: If either client.getPartitionIds() or client.send() fails, we can judge the connection has an error. Is my understanding right?
Is it possible to judge it before using it? 
Is there any way like client.isConnected =true?? or something?

Comment: Sorry. I'm new to Nodejs. I tried the code you posted. it throws an exception. So does it not return a promise?
The error is EventHubClient.createFromConnectionString(...).then is not a function.

Comment: I have updated the answer to include azure library imports as well, please note that you will need an azure iot hub key obtained from a event hub to create a client. Also if connection fails the error call back will be executed for `EventHubClient.createFromConnectionString(connStr, path)` method. so you can test whether connection has an error before executing anything else

Comment: Thanks. But it's useless. I don't think createFromConnectionString returns a promise.